# Behavior of stdin/stdout in conjunction with subshells and cd command

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, cd-command, subshell

I have the following series of commands:

```
cd / && ls | ( cd /tmp && cat >dumpfile)
```

This series of commands does the following: it creates a file named `/tmp/dumpfile`. This file contains a listing of the root directory.

The `cd / && ls` output gets piped to a subshell. What I find **odd** is that in the subshell, instead of  `cd /tmp` swallowing the `ls` output, the later `cat >dumpfile` gets it and writes it to a file. What is going on here?

Answer (score 8):

The pipe sets up stdout to go from `ls` to the subshell.

In the subshell, `cd /tmp` and `cat` are done in the same process.

`cd /tmp` doesn't read from stdin (the pipe), so when `cat` reads from stdin, it gets all of `ls`'s output.

Comment: Is it sufficient for the first command to have no process? What about `ls | ( /bin/echo hi; /bin/cat )` which runs `echo` and `cat` as separate processes, but `cat` still reads stdin from `ls` instead of `/bin/echo`?

Comment: If the first command is not a builtin, the shell will have to do an extra fork.  But that doesn't matter, because children inherit their parents' file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks! To elaborate on your answer even further: I checked the [cd's definition in IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html). In the "STDIN" and "STDOUT" sections it says both streams are (almost always) not used by cd.

Answer (score 3):

`cd` doesn't swallow the output because it doesn't want to. Consider this:

```
{ ls; date; } | (cd /tmp && date >> date.txt && cat date.txt && cat >dumpfile)
```

Only the last `cat >dumpfile` will save the `stdin` coming from the pipe, because none of the other commands want to consume it.